# Scanner stopped working (the scanner isn't available) - how to diagnose properly?

Tags: scanner, scanning, multi-function-printer

I have a HP 2320fxi that was running perfectly, all of a sudden scanning has stopped working.

Printing is still OK.

I am running Windows 8.1, connected over network (printer on static IP).

Can anyone please advise the proper fault finding routine with scanners?

So far I do:

- Checked i can ping and print to the printer - I can. Checked Windows
- Image Aquisition (WIA) service is running - it is.
- Control Panel -> View Scanners and Cameras, I can see the device listed.
- I click on the properties button, and a warning is displayed `The scanner isn't available. Make sure the device is turn on and is connected to your computer or the network`.

After the above, I get stuck, as I cant get in to properties to check IP address etc. In fact, I dont know how the printer has its address set!

How would one go from here, is this done by regedit or are there any command line tools available?

Answer (score 0):

I do have an answer for you, but you're probably not going to like it.

What you're going to need is a universal TWAIN driver because Win8.1 doesn't support direct WIA or TWAIN acquisition through the driver you have for your scanner... and this is is *normal* if your scanner's manufacturer stopped updating drivers before 2012.

I've been through this horror recently, and I've found a perfect solution - but it costs money, and I* don't mean pennies.

UniTwain.  http://www.terminalworks.com/unitwain

It costs $65. (Yes, you can try before you buy)   Worth every penny if you truly need it, and it works a treat with almost any imaging device there is.   It saved my virtual life in some respects after I used it just a few times.